# Sending emails with attachments but getting an IOException in Java

Tags: java, email-attachments, ioexception

I am unable to attach attachment files and then send it as email but i am able to send email without attachment,its generating an IOException when I try it send email having attachment with it.
I am trying to making an GUI for sending emails.

```
final String uid=jTextField1.getText();
//final String pass=jPasswordField1.get;
String pass = new String(jPasswordField1.getPassword());
String to=jTextField3.getText();
String sub=jTextField4.getText();
String data=jTextArea1.getText();

//server Config
Properties prop=new Properties();
prop.put("mail.smtp.auth","true");
prop.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
prop.put("mail.smtp.host","smtp.gmail.com");
prop.put("mail.smtp.port","587");
//client Authentication
Authenticator auth=new Authenticator()
{
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
    {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(uid,pass);
    }
};
//Session Creation
Session session= Session.getInstance(prop,auth);
//Message Creation
Message msg=new MimeMessage(session);
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(uid));
msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse(to));
msg.setSubject(sub);
msg.setText(data);
///*
//creating messege part
BodyPart msgbp = new MimeBodyPart();
//attachment
Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
//set text message part
msgbp.setText(data);
multipart.addBodyPart(msgbp);

// Part two is attachment
msgbp= new MimeBodyPart();
String filename = jTextField5.getText();
DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
msg.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
msg.setFileName(new File(jTextField5.getText()).getName());

multipart.addBodyPart(msgbp);

// Send the complete message parts
msg.setContent(multipart);

//*/
/*
byte[] attachmentData = null;  
Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
MimeBodyPart attachment = new MimeBodyPart();
InputStream attachmentDataStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(attachmentData);
attachment.setFileName(jTextField5.getText());
attachment.setContent(attachmentDataStream, "application/pdf");
mp.addBodyPart(attachment);
*/

//sending msg
Transport.send(msg);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"sent !");
} catch (MessagingException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
}
```

Comment: Can you print out `filename`? I bet it doesn't exist.

Comment: Show us the stack trace.  It will probably contain enough information to explain the error.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the exact exception that you're getting, including the stacktrace. Indicate which line of the code you posted is triggering the exception.

Comment: Attachment part is generating exception